# Application stack is very busy while executing a big task, need help for micro/alternative queue

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, queue

our NodeJS backend application has more than 200K users and every week we do some controls/calculations based on users. The operation is similar to this:

```js
const users = await dbService.user.findMany({}); // Array of 200K+ users
for (let index = 0; index < users.length; index++) {
  const user = users[index];
  const result = await checkUserSubscriptions({ id: user.id });
  // do operations according to result, mostly updateUser in database.
}
```

During the process, most of other requests are not executed or waited till this operation finishes. For example when a user tries to log in, they wait until this loop ends or they get a big delay. Because this operation does not need to be instant and can have delay or be slow, I need to use something else that does not block our main queue. What can I do to ensure this?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is like a background job and it shouldn't be in the same process of your web service. The memory usage of procesing 200K users will impact on your web service performance. Nodejs architecture is single-threaded and It doesn't matter if you try to run 200K async tasks, your web service performance will be affected.

You can see [worker_threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html), useful for performing CPU-intensive JavaScript operations. There are other packages that can helps you. You can take a look at [bull](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bull)

Comment: So, what do you suggest about Bull. Should I call the whole operations inside Bull at once or should I use it with Bull for each task?
For example:  for loop in users, get the user, do async job in Bull queue?

Comment: I would wrap the whole operation within one job, otherwise you would need to create to many jobs, but you know what is the best option according to your needs , see sections `Separate processes`, `Repeated jobs` and `Cluster support`,

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad practice to place an await inside a loop because it renders the code synchronous and you lose the ability for parallelism: each loop iteration has to wait for the previous one to complete before being triggered.

You should use `Promise.all`:

```
const users = await dbService.user.findMany({}); // Array of 200K+ users
const results = await Promise.all(users.map((user) => {
  return checkUserSubscriptions({ id: user.id });
}))
// results is an array of returned values from checkUserSubscriptions
```

Comment: I tried Promise.all. Actually it made server totally stuck and gave some errors because all of promises are executed so fast and that async operation includes requests to Revenuecat api.